# How to add CRUD to my app

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, crud

I'm a beginner I would like to add some CRUD functionality to my Console app. I'm struggling right now since I want to add a Object of type fish and an Object of type Reptile to an array and then print them, I want to make it possible by using a Menu which I've created but I can't figure out how to do that. The basic tests that I do to add objects from code throws me the error that it's out of bounds. I'm kind off very confused right now and I'm pretty sure my question is being poorly explained but I hope someone understood what I need help with here are my classes

**Here is the class that has the functions to Add An animal, or to Remove and to Display, this one include also the menu**

```
public class ZooManagement
{
    public Animal[] AnimalsList;
    public int length = 0;
    public int max_size;

    public void DisplayMenu() {
        int choice;
        try
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Welcome to our zoo menu\n\n");
                Console.Write("1. To add Animal\t");
                Console.Write("2. To remove Animal\t");
                Console.Write("3. To Display Animals ");

                choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        x.Add();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        x.Remove();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        x.Display();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("You've pressed something elss");
                        break;
                }
                Console.Write("\n\n\t\t\tNow press any button");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
            }
            while (choice != 3);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dont't be like that");
        }
    }      


    public ZooManagement(int x)
    {
        this.AnimalsList = new Animal[x];
        max_size = x;
    }

    //public void Array(int x)
    //{
    //    this.AnimalsList = new Animal[x];
    //    max_size = x;
    //}

    public void Add(Animal x)
    {
        if (this.length > this.max_size)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Out of bound Exception, Array full");
        }
        else
        {
            this.AnimalsList[this.length] = x;
            this.length++;
        }
    }

    public void Add(int h, Animal x)
    {
        if (h > this.length || h < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Out of bound Exception");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = (this.length); i >= h; i--) {
                this.AnimalsList[i + 1] = this.AnimalsList[i];
            }
            this.AnimalsList[h] = x;
            this.length++;
        }
    }

    public void Remove(Animal x)
    {
        int FoundAt = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        {
            if (this.AnimalsList[i] == x)
            {
                FoundAt = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (FoundAt != -1)
        {
            for (int i = FoundAt; i < this.length; i++)
            {
                this.AnimalsList[i] = this.AnimalsList[i + 1];
            }
            this.length--;
        }
    }

    public void Remove(int x)
    {
        if (x > this.length || x < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Out of bounds exception");
        }
        else
        {
            this.AnimalsList[x] = null;
            for (int i = x; i < this.length; i++)
            {
                this.AnimalsList[i] = this.AnimalsList[i + 1];
            }
            this.length--;
        }
    }


    public Animal GetAnimal(string reign)
    {
        if ("fish".Equals(reign))
        {
            return new Fish("", 0, 0, "", "");
        }
        else if ("reptile".Equals(reign))
        {
            return new Reptile("", 0, 0, "", "");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Animal Get(int x)
    {
        if (x > this.length || x < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Out of bounds Exeption");
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.AnimalsList[x];
        }
    }
    public void Set(int h, Animal x)
    {
        if (h > this.length || h < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Out of bounds Exeption");
        }
        else
        {
            this.AnimalsList[h] = x;
        }
    }

    public void Swap(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x >= 0 && x < length && y >= 0 && y < length)
        {
            Animal temp = AnimalsList[x];
            AnimalsList[x] = AnimalsList[y];
            AnimalsList[y] = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Out of bounds exception");
        }
    }

    public void Swap(Animal x, Animal y)
    {
        int FoundAtA = -1;
        int FoundAtB = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i <this.length; i++)
        {
            if(this.AnimalsList[i] == x)
            {
                FoundAtA = i;
                if(FoundAtA != -1 && FoundAtB != -1)
                    {
                    break;
                    } 
            }
            else if(this.AnimalsList[i] == y)
            {
                FoundAtB = i;
                if(FoundAtA != -1 && FoundAtB != -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
        if (FoundAtA != -1 && FoundAtB != -1)
        {
            this.Swap(FoundAtA, FoundAtB);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Out of bounds Exeption");
        }
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.AnimalsList[i]);
        }
    }
}
    //public static double AnimalWeight(int weight, int size)
    //{
    //    return (weight * 703) / (size * size);
    //}
}
```

*** Here is the main***

```
public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ZooManagement x = new ZooManagement(10);
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Animal petru = new Fish("Piranha", 22, 33, "M", "round");
        Animal petra = new Reptile("Snake", 33, 44, "F", "long");
        x.Add(4, petru);
        x.Add(5, petra);
        x.Display();
        x.Swap(petru, petra);
        x.Display();
        Console.ReadKey();
        x.DisplayMenu();
}
}
```

**And here is the fish class that has some stats and behaviours from abstract Animl class**

```
class Fish : Animal, IFood ,ILimbless
{

    public string shape;
    private string v;

    public string Shape { get; set; }

    private string GetFishShape(string shape)
    {
        return shape;
    }

    public override string Behavior()
    {
        return "Passive";
    }

    public void  Eats()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Eats alges and fish");
    }

    public override string MakeNoise()
    {
        return "Doesnt make noises LOL";
    }


    public void Slither(string w)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It is limbless that's why it slithers");
    }

    public Fish(string raceInfo, int weight, double size, string sex, string shape) : base(raceInfo, weight, size, sex)
    {
        this.raceInfo = raceInfo;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.size = size;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.shape = shape;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment - is it? Generally you won't get much help, if any, for homework assignments.

Comment: What does any of this have to do with "CRUD"?  Focus on the specific error you're getting.  What line throws the error?  What are the values when it happens?

Comment: Please post minimal error related code, not all program.

Comment: It's not a homework in country where I live we do Pascal and algorithms, I try to study by myself, I don;t really have the error it works but it doesnt add to the array the objects I try to add...

Comment: Do you add? then you have C(reate), do you read data? then you have CR(ead). Alter stuff? CRU(pdate). Lastly do you delete? Then you have CRUD(elete). Its not something we can make for you. *The D in CRUD is not **display***

Comment: Im not asking you to make this app for me OMG, I just can't figure out where im wrong, and Why it doesnt do what I  think it should, The Issue is that It doesnt add the object when I call the function, and that means I can't display or remove. An object

Comment: @J.Doe Ask a single question then, don't say `I want to add some crud` because no one can do that for you

Comment: Do you know how to debug? Debug and you will see why.

Comment: @Reniuz Uhmm not really

Comment: @J.Doe Then that's a good place to start learning to program (as most issues from juniors to seniors are solved by debugging.) https://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: You wrote `code throws me the error that it's out of bounds` Without any questions you should answer to your self why it is throws error, because you wrote code line `Console.WriteLine("Out of bound Exception");` Because it is your code you should know why you notifying about error.

Comment: @Reniuz well that's what I meant...

Comment: And we came to the point where you asking us to debug your code. And this is off-topic in SO. Please read this: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Now is the time to learn debugging. This will flip your programming experience upside down.:)

Answer (score 0):

You never clean the `length`. To make sure that length is indeed used correct you should put length to 0 again in initialization.

```
public ZooManagement(int x)
{
    this.AnimalsList = new Animal[x];
    this.max_size = x;
    this.length = 0;
}
```

Next to that please consider renaming the variable `length`, since in arrays it does have different meaning.

---

Sidenote:
It might be wise to remove the ifs too check if it is within the bounds. If it isn't within the bounds it will throw a more clear error then this. If you don't want errors to pop up, then rather use trycatch, and if it fails then be sure that you log an unique and clear error.